# Oracle Insert Special Characters and Function Names

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, escaping, special-characters

I´m currently struggling to insert a value into a varchar2 column off an Oracle Database. The value is (and full of special characters....):

```
'Data\QVD\QVD_'& replace(v_sc_val_ExecutionEnvironment, chr(39),'') &'\VTB_MOD1_RESULT\'
```

(Its a QlikView Formular which should be stored in the Database. Afterwards I can extract and evaluate it with QlikView, but I need the exact given format.)

I already tried to escape all ' with '' and so on, but It didn´t work so far. Define off didn´t work too.

I also found:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm
but didn´t find a solution there.

Hopefully someone had the same problems or knows the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work so far"? What do you insert (show us your command) and what do you get?

Comment: I know nothing about QlikView but any decent technology with database support should have prepared statements or, at least, a builtin escape function. You can't do it manually, it'd be crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the [q quote operator](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218):

```
insert into yourTable(c)
values ( q'['Data\QVD\QVD_'& replace(v_sc_val_ExecutionEnvironment, chr(39),'') &'\VTB_MOD1_RESULT\']').
```

This way you should need no escape and the text should be inserted exactly as you typed it.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
This solved my Problem. Do you see any downside using this on any string insert?

Comment: Oracle gives no restriction about this; I believe this is the best way to handle strings with quotes and special characters.

Comment: Thanks again, you helped me alot.

Comment: Of course, if you use `]'` as end delimiter you need to ensure that your string literal does not end with `]'`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I was just answering you "Thanks, editing the answer", but I made a try and it seems to me that Oracle handles well the quotes, even if my string ends with a ']'; for example, `select q'[[]]' from dual` gives me `[]`

Comment: @Aleksej That string ends with `]`, not `]'`. But that's how escaping works: no matter what delimiter you choose, you need to escape the delimiter itself when it isn't supposed to be a delimiter (or pick a different delimiter). Prepared statements or builtin escape functions save you from all the hassle.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Stupid me, I completely missed your point. You're absolutely right, thanks